# python unpack into multiple optional variables

Tags: python, unpack

In Perl, I can do

```
($x1, $x2, $x3, $x4) = (1, 2)
```

Then $x1 and $x2 are 1; $x3 and $x4 are 'undef'

Does Python has something similar to this

```
(x1, x2, x3, x4) = [1,2]
```

so that x1 and x2 are 1; x3 and x4 are None?

I tried above, Python gives me error:

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

I tried to use * operator for optional unpacking

```
(x1, x2, *x3, *x4) = [1,2]
```

but * can only be used once.

Thank you for your advice.

Background: the List (array) on the right hand side can be any length between 1 and 4. I use [1,2] just for example.

Comment: There is nothing similar in Python.

Comment: sad but may be true. thank you wim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a few `None`s and sweep any excess ones under the carpet (using the brush symbol `*` and the carpet symbol `_` :-):

```
x1, x2, x3, x4, *_ = lst + [None] * 4
```

Comment: this is indeed the best we can get in python